# What is the purpose of the 80th column marker?

Tags: netbeans, coding-style

I just switched to netbeans and the 80th column marker was on by default. What is the purpose of the 80th column marker?

[image]

Comment: It something from "the old days" when screen had a lot crappierresolutions. It's just a visible guideline to tell you you code lines are getting too long. Nowadays I often use something like 120.

Answer (score 1):

It's so that if you use a coding convention which requires all code to be less than 80 columns wide, it makes it easy to see when you're going over the limit. Even though monitors are much wider than they used to be, an 80 (or 100, or whatever) column limit can stil be advantageous so that you can always compare code side-by-side without wrapping during code review.

I expect you can turn it off if you're *not* interested in sticking to certain column limits.

(Eclipse has the same feature, by the way.)

Answer (score 0):

80 characters is the typical number of characters that can fit on a single line from a printer.  Most IDE's have that value set so that you can see what will fit onto a printout